# How to solve "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'"

Tags: c++

This error has appeared in countless posts, but with my limited knowledge of c++ i am unable to adapt any of the suggested solutions to my problem.
The first problem I have is in the fifth of the declarations below:

```
static void write_cntinfo(ofstream &, const CNTInfo &);
static void write_ctsinfo(ofstream &, const CTSInfo &);
static void write_mctsinfo(ofstream &, const MCTSInfo &);
static void write_nbrcntinfo(ofstream &, const NBRCNTInfo &);
static void read_ldf( const *, int, NumArray &);
```

which error is:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 static void read_ldf( const *, int, NumArray &);
                         ^
```

and in

```
void compute_cts_stats_ci_bca(const gsl_rng *rng_ptr,
                          const NumArray &f_na,
                          const NumArray &o_na,
                          int b, CTSInfo *&cts_info, int n_cts,
                          int cts_flag, int rank_flag,
                          const *tmp_dir) {

error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘tmp_dir’ with no type [-fpermissive]
const *tmp_dir) {
       ^~~~~~~
```

But there are many many errors of "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'", first off

```
   for(i=0; i<n_cts; i++) {
  prefix << cs_erase << tmp_dir << "/tmp_cts_i_" << i;
  cts_i_file[i] = make_temp_file_name(prefix, '\0');

  prefix << cs_erase << tmp_dir << "/tmp_cts_r_" << i;
  cts_r_file[i] = make_temp_file_name(prefix, '\0');
 }

error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘ConcatString’ and ‘const int*’)
   prefix << cs_erase << tmp_dir << "/tmp_cts_i_" << i;
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
   prefix << cs_erase << tmp_dir << "/tmp_cts_i_" << i;
                         ^~~~~~~
```

The whole file is accessible here

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qj-WvNZUimVpxYOTYjgYVErRp1-GG0te (https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive).
```

any assistance will be appreciated.

Firstly I must mention that my knowledge of c++ is next to zero.
Secondly this program is part of programs for compiling a software. I have no idea what it is doing, except that I do experience the errors in the course of compiling the software.
The error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'" was appearing prominently, but only after "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]". Thanks to directions given by @Daltenwolf I have been able to eliminate these two errors.
I now have to contend with the error:

```
compute_ci.cc:347:51: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
   cts_i_file[i] = make_temp_file_name(prefix, char'\0');
```

which appears on several lines. The "char" in "char'\0'' was added by me.

The other error I have on a few lines is

```
compute_ci.cc: In function ‘void write_cntinfo(std::ofstream&, const CNTInfo&)’:
compute_ci.cc:3832:4: error: ‘line’ was not declared in this scope
line[max_line_len];
^~~~
```

I am very thankful to Daltenwolf.

Comment: There's no such error "invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'" in the list of errors you show us. And the very first error you show us is quite clear about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler error messages actually are telling you exactly what the problem is:

```
static void read_ldf( const *, int, NumArray &);
                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Something is missing there. `const` is a type qualifier that modifies whatever is written *left* of it (except if `const` is the first token of a statement, then it acts toward the *right*).

And the `*` means "make this a pointer".

But there's something missing: The actual type of what the whole thing is concerned with. Without the type the rest of the statement makes no sense. Unfortunately we can't even guess what the right type would be to use there.

---

The other error message also has to do with types. Something (the `operator <<` in your case) expects a `char const *` (that's the type in which strings are usually passed around in C; also often C++, but in C++ you really should use `std::string`) but whatever you've wrote there gives only a `char`, i.e. a single character, which according to the rules of the language also behaves like integer. In fact `char` is the integer type with usually the fewest bits.

---

Both problems are fixed by making sure the types properly fit together. And by that I don't mean to slap typecasts onto it, but to make sure, that the pieces you try to fit together actually match.

Comment: The `int` probably comes from old default-to-int rules in GCC. That tends to crop up in subsequent error messages whenever you forgot to properly declare something with a meaningful type. In other words, there's really just the one problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The error is simple and clear from the compiler error message:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type
```

And indeed, `parameter` has no type. Did you miss a `char` here?

```
static void read_ldf( const char*, int, NumArray &);
```

Same for the other function, and all the other errors stem from this missing type (as the type would be default to `int` instead).